How to get Request.RawURL to my Function written in MS Java
I am trying to get the Request.RawURL string on an ASP error in Global.aspx.
Here is my code snippet as written in MS JavaScript:
function Application_Error(sender:Object, e:EventArgs)
{
    var sIP:String=Request.ServerVariables("Remote_Addr")
    var sError:String;
    var err:HttpException=Server.GetLastError();
    sError="<h1>"+err.InnerException.Message+"</h1>";
    var sMsg=err.GetHtmlErrorMessage().ToString();
    sError+="<p>"+sMsg+"</p>";

I did not write this. I am not familiar with this function.
I hope this is enough information.
Thanks
I found another code snippet that is written in C#:
   protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       // Code that runs when an unhandled error occurs
        HttpException lastErrorWrapper = Server.GetLastError() as HttpException;
        Exception lastError = lastErrorWrapper;
        if (lastErrorWrapper.InnerException != null)
            lastError = lastErrorWrapper.InnerException;
        string lastErrorTypeName = lastError.GetType().ToString();
        string lastErrorMessage = lastError.Message;
        string lastErrorStackTrace = lastError.StackTrace;
        string YSODmarkup = lastErrorWrapper.GetHtmlErrorMessage();
        const string ToAddress = "xxxxxx";
        const string FromAddress = "xxxxxx";
        const string sWebsite="xxxxx (2020 Website)";
        const string Subject = "An Error Has Occured at "+sWebsite;
        string sCIP=Request.ServerVariables["Remote_Addr"];
        string sAgent = Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_User_Agent"];
        //Create MailMessage object//
        System.Net.Mail.MailMessage mm = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage(FromAddress, ToAddress);
        mm.Subject = Subject;
        mm.IsBodyHtml = true;
        mm.Priority = System.Net.Mail.MailPriority.High;
        mm.Body = string.Format(@"
        <html><head></head><body style=""font-family:verdana;"">
            <h1 style=""font-family:Verdana; font-size:10px; font-weight: bold;"">An Error Has Occurred!</h1>
            <table cellpadding=""5"" cellspacing=""0"" border=""1"">
                <tr>
                    <td style=""text-align: right;font-weight: bold"">URL:</td>
                    <td>{0}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style=""text-align: right;font-weight: bold"">IP Address:</td>
                    <td>{1}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style=""text-align: right;font-weight: bold"">User Agent:</td>
                    <td>{2}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style=""text-align: right;font-weight: bold"">Exception Type:</td>
                    <td>{3}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style=""text-align: right;font-weight: bold"">Message:</td>
                    <td>{4}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </body>
        </html>",
                Request.RawUrl,
                sCIP,
                sAgent,
                lastErrorTypeName,
                lastErrorMessage,
                YSODmarkup,
                lastErrorStackTrace.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />"));
        //Attach the Yellow Screen of Death for this error
        //string YSODmarkup = lastErrorWrapper.GetHtmlErrorMessage();


This has the Request.RawUrl string.
